# How does avgqu-sz size in iostat output relate to r_await and w_await?

Tags: linux, performance, io, iostat

Can someone explain what does `avgqu-sz` mean in the output of iostat? The manual page states like this.

```
avgqu-sz:
   The average queue length of the requests that were issued to the device.
```

Can someone help me understand this a little more?

In one of my dev setup I am observing `avgqu-sz` value like below. All the column values are the 95 percentile value per hour. Can someone help me understand how does `avgqu-sz` relate to other iostat fields (like `r_await`, `w_await`, `r/s`, `w/s`, etc) ?

```
                   timestamp               r/s       w/s     r_await    w_await   avgqu-sz                                          
0         2020-04-25 00:53:59.249999872  4435.01   8310.81    3.6800    4.0600    13.9630
1         2020-04-25 01:53:59.249999872  5943.15   7308.96    3.7515    3.8610    12.9740
2         2020-04-25 02:53:59.249999872  4573.45  11083.89    3.1805    3.6810    14.8125
3         2020-04-25 03:53:59.249999872  4561.46  10301.63    4.1515    3.1830    18.7635
4         2020-04-25 04:53:59.249999872  3330.91   8764.82    7.0130    2.7810    16.7215
5         2020-04-25 05:53:55.500000000  4864.52   8316.68    4.9310    3.0810    14.2320
6         2020-04-25 06:53:55.249999872  5503.61   6356.95    4.1220    2.7810    12.5010
7         2020-04-25 07:02:32.500000000  4759.70   6532.80    3.2750    4.5400    15.4650
8         2020-04-24 08:56:58.249999872  4959.69   6939.54    2.7510    5.3245    14.9455
9         2020-04-24 09:56:58.249999872  1929.14   6888.51    2.9305    2.6310    13.0260
10        2020-04-24 10:56:58.249999872  2814.69   7053.62    2.9200    2.6410    14.2835
11        2020-04-24 11:56:58.249999872  4270.01   6513.56    1.5305    1.6500    13.1110
12        2020-04-24 12:56:59.249999872  9818.74   6061.77    1.7100    3.6725    20.5005
13        2020-04-24 13:56:59.249999872  6318.94   8868.55    1.5800    3.0890    15.8160
14        2020-04-24 14:56:59.249999872  5177.97   7995.32    1.7810    2.1300    14.1155
15        2020-04-24 15:56:59.249999872  4031.30   8081.75    1.8205    1.7010    12.9030
16        2020-04-24 16:56:59.249999872  2508.38   7748.61    1.8405    1.5405    11.9430
17        2020-04-24 17:56:59.249999872  3878.49   9050.67    2.0405    1.7410    15.3910
18        2020-04-24 18:56:59.249999872  4269.47   8221.51    2.2805    1.6200    14.6525
19        2020-04-24 19:56:59.249999872  3592.69   7610.89    1.7705    1.7510    13.4725
20        2020-04-24 20:56:59.249999872  6622.17   7555.09    2.9405    2.8940    17.3830
21        2020-04-24 21:56:59.249999872  5120.35   7667.93    1.8810    2.3420    13.4915
22        2020-04-24 22:56:59.249999872  3242.21   8541.93    1.4305    1.4800    11.9405
23        2020-04-24 23:56:59.249999872  3238.35   7517.56    1.5310    1.8220    10.8105
```

Comment: Could you annotate fields so we know what values you present?

Comment: I have updated the question. Somehow this got missed while posting. Thanks for pointing this out.